# Problema ao fazer upload com php

Tags: php

Estou fazendo upload com php pro servidor. No começo funcionou perfeitamente. O problema e que agora quando ele faz o upload para a pasta no servidor ele altera o nome.

```
<?php

try {

    if (
        !isset($_FILES['arquivo']['error']) ||
        is_array($_FILES['arquivo']['error'])
    ) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Parametros invalidos. Contate o administrador.');
    }

    switch ($_FILES['arquivo']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException('O arquivo não foi selecionado.');
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException('O arquivo excedeu o tamanho máximo permitido (5mb).');
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Erro desconhecido. Contate o administrador.');
    }

    if ($_FILES['arquivo']['size'] > 5242880) {
        throw new RuntimeException('O arquivo excedeu o tamanho máximo permitido (5mb).');
    }


    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('<br />Arquivo com formato invalido (Extenção permitida: PDF).<br />');
    }

    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'],
        sprintf('Documentos/%s.%s',
            sha1_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']),
            $ext
        )
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException('<br />Falha ao fazer upload do arquivo. Contate o administrador.<br />');
    }

    echo '<br />Arquivo enviado com sucesso <br />';

} catch (RuntimeException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
?>
```

Como faço para ele fazer o upload com o nome original do arquivo e não com o tmp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'],
    sprintf('Documentos/%s.%s', sha1_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']), $ext)
```

Note que, neste trecho de código, você faz o upload do arquivo **tmp_name**, com destino **Documentos/ArquivoTemporário.ext**.

Inclusive, você acabou deixando a extensão do arquivo (*$ext*) fora da função **sprintf**.

```
 $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'] //nome temporário do arquivo no servidor
 $_FILES['arquivo']['name']     //nome original do arquivo do computador do usuário
```

Você precisa fazer o upload com o nome original do arquivo.

```
 if (!move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], sprintf('Documentos/%s.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'], $ext)))
```

Lembrando que no código acima, foi retirado a função **sha1_file**, que criaria um hash do arquivo. No entanto, você mencionou querer salvar com o nome original.

Em última instancia, o sistema de arquivos do PHP nos dá uma função para renomear arquivos. Você pode consulta-la na documentação:

[PHP: rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Comment: Eu tentei com o name na sprintf mais não coloquei a ext na frente. Vou tentar quando chegar em casa. Obrigado.

Comment: Amigo tive que fazer umas alterações no código que você me passou `if (!move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'],
    sprintf('Documentos/%s.', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'], $ext)))` e agora funcionou Perfeitamente, do jeito que me passou ele escrevia a extensão no nome e mais o .pdf, exemplo.pdf.pdf. Mais muitoooo obrigado se não fosse sua ajuda eu ia me bater por muito tempo.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu seu problema @WillianCoqueiro :)
Bom, passou despercebido. Já editei a resposta.